# Proving equivalency of locus and described curve

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, parametric, locus

The locus of a geometric figure can be obtained by encapsulating the known properties of the figure in some parametric equations, and then combining them into a single equation.

As I understand it, though, the equations aren't usually further examined to make sure that the locus curve and the figure are completely equivalent. That all the points of the initially specified geometric figure are present on the obtained locus is always true (obviously), but apparently it isn't required to check if we end up obtaining extra points that satisfy the final locus equation in some way, but aren't a part of the intended figure. Admittedly, I've never had cases where I got loci that had extraneous points, but it still seems necessary to check.

For example, a question requires me to find the locus of the centroid of the triangle formed by the varying points $$(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha) \\(\sin \alpha, -\cos \alpha) \\ (1, 2), $$ and the parametric equations turn out to be $$3x-1=\sin\alpha+ \cos \alpha\\3y-2=\sin \alpha-\cos \alpha. $$ On squaring and adding them, we get the equation of a circle, $$(3x-1)^2+(3y-2)^2=2 \tag{*} $$

Here, all that I seem to have done is prove that a point satisfying the intended figure will necessarily satisfy ( * ), not that if a point satisfies ( * ), it will necessarily be part of the locus. I had to draw out the graphs of the trigonometric equations obtained from the R.H.S of the parametric equations to convince myself that both the sum and difference of $\cos$ and $\sin$ would only go so far as $\pm\sqrt{2} $, and that every possible $a$ and $b$ for which $a^2+b^2=2$ could be constructed by the various combinations (using signs) of the two, and that thus, the locus and the intended figure were equivalent.

Proving that the figure *lies* on the locus is easy, but proving the converse may take effort, maybe sometimes more than in this case. So is there really a reason to prove this equivalence, or is it always unnecessary?

Comment: *"apparently it isn't required to check if we end up obtaining extra points that satisfy the final locus equation in some way"* ... Oh, it's definitely "required", if the goal is to capture the locus and only the locus. However, textbook examples and such *tend* to not to give extraneous cases, or they're framed as exercises in finding the equation of the curve that *contains* the locus (which allows extra points). A simple example is the locus of points $P$ such that $|PF|-|PG|$ is a some constant; the locus is just *one branch* of the hyperbola encoded by the associated Cartesian equation.

Comment: True Story: Last week, I was exploring a locus of points in GeoGebra using the "trace point" feature on a dynamic figure. Satisfied that I understood the behavior, I went off to derive the equation, which I subsequently entered into the app, only to be shown an *entirely different* curve. I spent an embarrassing amount of time re-checking my work and looking for typos in my equations. As it turned out, the traced points in my diagram were still visible on-screen, covering the expected "branch" of the curve I'd derived; so, all I noticed were extraneous points that I *should have* anticipated.

Comment: This is one reason why Cartesian eqns are pretty lousy for describing loci; all they do is capture a static set of points that happen to satisfy a relation. Parametric eqns do a better job because they encode how to traverse the points in a *path* (which is key to studying the geometry and physics of that path); to the specific issue of the question, parametric equations make it easier to, say, prescribe starting and ending values of the associated parameter, trimming a curve to *just* the path needed for the desired locus. (All that said, extraneous pts sometimes have useful interpretations.)

Comment: @Blue: thanks, that answers everything!